# Mocking complex query with several objects

Tags: spring, mockito

How should I go about mocking this query, so that I receive a pre-defined `ArrayList<Follow>`?

I've tried a number of ways but they've all been clunky and... don't work because I don't know how to deal with add().

```
result = (ArrayList<Follow>) session.createCriteria(Follow.class).add(Restrictions.eq("followerUsername", followerUsername)).list();
```

Comment: Why not extract that code into a method that takes `followerUsername` as an argument and return `ArrayList<Follow>` as a result, and then mock that new method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally extract the code into another method and then just mock that method.
It would look like:

```
ArrayList<Follow> getFollowListByUsername(String followerUsername) {
   return (ArrayList<Follow>) session.createCriteria(Follow.class).add(Restrictions.eq("followerUsername", followerUsername)).list()
}
```

Then all you need to do is mock the `getFollowListByUsername` method which is extremely easy.